# How to fix error "invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'goelv' " when trying to capture string

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-urls

I have the following urls.py

```
urlpatterns = patterns('accounts.views',
  url(r'^user/(?P<id>\w+)/$', 'profile'),
)
```

I have the following views.py

```
def profile(request, id):
  user = UserProfile.objects.get(user__username=id)
  product = Mattress.objects.filter(owner = id)   #PROBLEM IS IN THIS LINE
  c = RequestContext(request, {
    'action': 'update/',
    'button': 'Update', 
    'profile': user,
    'product': product,
  })
  return render_to_response('registration/user_profile.html', c)
```

When I type in the url "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/goelv/", the id "goelv" is succesfully captured. However, I'm getting the error < invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'goelv' > which traces to my views.py in the line product=Mattress.objects.filter(owner = id).

For reference, I have the following models.py where the owner field simply correlates to a User object

```
class Product(models.Model):
  owner = models.ForeignKey(User, null=True, blank=True)
  title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
  manufacturer = models.CharField(max_length=75)
  product_description = models.TextField(max_length=2000)
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong or how to go about fixing this problem? Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are referring to `id`, then it should be `integer` not string.

However, this would solve your problem.

```
product = Mattress.objects.filter(owner = user)
```

Note: using `user` instead of `id` in filter as you have already retrieved user object.